# Conjugate function of squared $\ell_2$-norm in terms of Euclidean projection?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $\|\cdot\|$ be $\ell_2$-norm in $\mathcal{R}^n$, and $\psi(x)=\frac{1}{2}\|x\|^2$ for $x \in X$ and $+\infty$ for $x \notin X$. Show that conjugate of $\psi(x)$ is given by $\psi^*:\mathcal{R}^n \rightarrow \mathcal{R}$
$$
\psi^*(z)=\frac{1}{2}(\|z\|^2 -\|z -\pi_X(z)\|^2)
$$

where $\pi_X(x)=\arg \min \{\|x-y\|\mid y \in X\}$ is Euclidean projection onto $X$.

Answer (score 0):

By definition,
\begin{align}
\Psi^*(z) &= \sup_x \, \langle z, x \rangle - \Psi(x) \\
&= \sup_{x \in X} \, \langle z, x \rangle - \frac12 \| x \|_2^2.
\end{align}
Now complete the square:
$$
\langle z, x \rangle - \frac12 \| x \|_2^2 = 
-\frac12 \left( \|x - z \|_2^2  - \|z\|_2^2\right) = \frac12 \|z\|_2^2 - \frac12 \|x - z \|_2^2.
$$
It follows that
\begin{align}
\Psi^*(z) &= \sup_{x \in X} \,\frac12 \|z\|_2^2 - \frac12 \|x - z \|_2^2 \\
&= \frac12 \|z\|_2^2 - \frac12 \|z - \Pi_X(z) \|_2^2.
\end{align}